# Why is if (a,b = [nil, nil]) truthy in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, if-statement

I'm studying Ruby now, and I don't understand why the test condition

```rb
if (a,b = [nil, nil]) # <--
  true
else
  false
end
```

evaluates as truthy, while

```rb
if (a,b = nil) # <--
  true
else
  false
end
```

is falsy as advertised.

Tested on ruby 2.5 and 2.7 via `irb`. Added a complete if-else statement for your copy-paste testing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assignments evaluate to the same value as the right operand of the assignment. This is still true for destructuring assignments.

So `a,b = [nil, nil]` evaluates to `[nil, nil]`, which truthy because it's an array and arrays are truthy, whereas `a,b = nil` evaluates to `nil`, which is falsy.

Comment: A ruby newbie like me thinks it would be the destructured values that are evaluated for truthiness. I imagine this as easily a bug that would've haunted me for hours.

Comment: @Nogurenn Which one though? That is, should `a,b = [true, false]` evaluate to `true` or to `false`?

Comment: Somehow. That's why I was expecting `[nil, nil]` to be falsy. I assumed it would evaluate with an `AND` logic testing each value from left to right. I realized it's too ambiguous in the first place.

Comment: @Nogurenn Note that the condition of an if statement is evaluated to a value using the same evaluation rules as in any other context. And then it simply checks whether that value is truthy or not. So the value checked for truthiness when you do `if a,b = [true, false]` is the same value that would be printed when you run `p (a,b = [true, false])`, for example. And I think it's pretty clear that it wouldn't make much sense for `p (a,b = [true, false])` to print out a single boolean value.

Comment: @Nogurenn: "A ruby newbie like me thinks it would be the destructured value**s** that are evaluated for truthiness." – Exactly. The value**s**. Plural. And how do you represent multiple values? With an array. And what is the boolean value of an array?

Answer (score 2):

In ruby, only 2 values are false, which are `nil` and `false` itself.

All other values are truth, including arrays of nils.

Also, assign operation returns right side of assignment, so

```
(a,b = [nil, nil]) == [nil, nil]
(a,b = nil) == nil
```

Comment: @sepp2k sent an answer 22 seconds earlier. You still get an upvote though. :)